# O que fazer quando o token gerado expira?

Tags: c#, rest, restful, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-2

Estou desenvolvendo uma API `rest` com o Framework `Asp.Net Web Api 2`, usando `Owin`.
Tenho uma aplicação `android` como o cliente. No caso, meu sistema tem os usuários e senhas e autentica normalmente.
Quero saber o que fazer quando o `token` expirar. Autenticar novamente?

Comment: O problema é que está expirando muito rápido? ou só é a duvida quando o token terminar seu período de validade?

Comment: O que devo fazer quando o token expirar, não faço nada e espero o usuário autenticar novamente?

Comment: Em toda ação que precisa da requisição, o `token` deve ser enviado, a partir do momento que ele não é válido, o usuário recebe uma mensagem ou é redirecionado para autenticação novamente. Bom eu entendi isso se por ventura não for pode dizer!

Comment: O cliente pode utilizar o refresh token para renovar o token de acesso. Você pode entender mais sobre esse processo aqui: https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/